Need an elegant solution for a geometric probability problem

Consider a square $S \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ in the first quadrant with unit side length such that one of its vertices coincides with the origin and the sides of $S$ are parallel to the coordinate axes. Let $I$ be a circle of radius $0 < r < \frac{1}{2}$ centered at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. Find the probability $P_{r}$ that the line segment joining any two distinct points chosen uniformly on $S$ has atleast one point in common with the interior of the circle $I$. (Note that $S$ and $I$ implicitly denotes the boundary/circumference of their respective figures)

Although the question is pretty elegant, the solution I came up for this problem is quite lengthy and involves some mathematical labour :-
Suppose that two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ are picked on $S$. Assume WLOG that $P_1$ lies on the X - axis, we can do so because of the symmetrical nature of the problem. Now, draw tangents from $P_1$ to $I$ which intersects $S$ upon extension at two distinct points $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.
Note that since $P_1$ lies on the X - axis, $P_1 \equiv (h,0)$ for some $0 \le h \le 1$. Also note that one of the arcs (not necessarily the smaller one) along $S$ between the points $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ contains the locus of all those points $P_2$ such that $P_1P_2$ passes through the interior of $I$. If we let $L(h)$ denote the length of this arc, the probability of success becomes $\frac{L(h)}{4}$. Hence, our final answer shall turn out to be
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{L(h)}{4} dh,$$
by considering infinitesimally small intervals $(h, h + dh)$ on the X - axis and integrating over the complete domain.
On the surface the solution looks neat, but calculating $L(h)$ by using cartesian coordinates and considering multiple cases seems to be laborious. Its not something I would deem as impossible, but I feel that there is better way to calculate $L(h)$ or there is an altogether different approach to tackle the original problem.
Therefore any hints to complete this proof or alternate solutions would be gladly welcomed. Do feel free to discuss any flaws in my arguments.

You could draw (1) a tangent from P1 to Q1 such that the center C of the circle lies to the right of the ray from P1 to Q!, and then (2) another tangent where $C$ lies to the left of the ray. Then the arc is the one going clockwise from Q1 to Q2 which saves you some guesswork/fiddling. Other than that, your approach seems viable but, as you observe, annoying.

Do you have a good reason for centering everything at $(1/2,1/2)$ rather than at the origin? I find this an unnecessary distraction.

Well we do have the four fold symmetry when the circle is centred at (1/2, 1/2), but with the center at the origin we would have more manual calculations

I think you can simplify somewhat by thinking of a double integral. First define a function: for each pair of points $U, V$ on the square, compute the distance from the segment UV to the circle center; if it's less than $r$, then $f(U, V) = 1$; if it's greater than or equal to $r$, then $f(U, V) = 0$. The thing you now want is
$$
\frac{ \int_{U \in S} \int_{V \in S} f(U, V) dV dU }
{ \int_{U \in S} \int_{V \in S} 1 ~~dV dU }.
$$
The denominator here is $16$, so that's easy. And if we divide $S$ into its four sides, B, L, T, R (bottom, left, top, right), then the numerator is just four times (as you've observed) the result you get by considering $U \in B$, which is
\begin{align}
\int_{U \in B}& \int_{V \in S} f(U, V) dV dU  \\
&=
{ \int_{U \in B} \int_{V \in L} f(U, V) dV dU }
+{ \int_{U \in B} \int_{V \in T} f(U, V) dV dU }
+{ \int_{U \in B} \int_{V \in R} f(U, V) dV dU }\\
&= 2{ \int_{U \in B} \int_{V \in L} f(U, V) dV dU }
+{ \int_{U \in B} \int_{V \in T} f(U, V) dV dU }
\end{align}
because if $U$ and $V$ are both in $B$, there's surely no intersection.
Each of the two remaining integrals should be not-so-hard (I hope).
What I've done here is more or less simplify the computation you need to do about 'arc length' to just "arc length within one side", while also exploiting symmetry a bit more. In fact, you could use more symmetry and take $U$ to be in the left half of $B$ and $V$ to be in the left half of $S$, which reduces to "all of L, and the left half of T", and that seems as if it'd be pretty manageable.

Hmm, I think I get the idea. You essentially converted my work on considering different cases into the splitting of integrals. Thank you :)

I still suspect that there's a much easier way to even do those integrals, but I couldn't work it out last night as I fell asleep, so I guess I'll abandon it.
